# Incompatible types when returning PageFactory.initElements

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I am using appium java-client 4.1.2 and selenium 3.1.0

So I have this method that returns a RegisterSelectionPage object when a button is clicked on the main screen. The code snippet below belongs to the MainScreen Page Object where there is a function to click the register button.

```
public RegisterSelectionPage clickRegister(){
    registerButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.test.app:id/btn_register"));
    registerButton.click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), RegisterSelectionPage.class);
}
```

The return line is basically underlined as red in IntelliJ and a warning says that the types are incompatible.

> Required: com.example.app.screens.RegisterSelectionPage Found: void

This seems to be only happening when PageFactory.initElements() is the 'return' object.

To give more context, the RegisterSelectionPage looks like:

```
public class RegisterSelectionPage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "")//will add the later
    WebElement registerWithEmailLink;

    public RegisterSelectionPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to run the code if you ignore this warning.

Comment: No. I finally settled with just PageFactory.initElements(driver, this). Without the AppiumFieldDecorator. This seems to solve my problem for now but I doubt I could use the annotations such as AndroidFindBy if I dont use the FieldDecorator.